# Docker nginx & fpm: Error 404 on my nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, moodle

I try to run a php application with fpm for [this](https://github.com/ellakcy/docker-moodle/tree/dev) project. And I am trying to make the nginx image to run the fpm based solution. My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```yml
version: '2'
services:

# apache based images

  # A base image for apache - based moodle builds
  moodle_apache_base:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: dockerfiles/apache/Dockerfile_base
      image: ellakcy/moodle:apache_base

  # Mysql running variant
  moodle_mysql_db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  moodle_mysql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/apache/Dockerfile_mysql
    image: ellakcy/moodle:mysql_maria_apache
    links:
      - "moodle_mysql_db:moodle_db"
      - "moodle_apache_base"
    ports:
      - "6080:80"
    environment:
      MOODLE_DB_HOST: "moodle_mysql_db"
      MOODLE_DB_NAME: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MOODLE_DB_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN: "${MOODLE_ADMIN}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_URL: "http://0.0.0.0:6080"

  # postgresql running variant
  moodle_psql_db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      POSTGRES_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  moodle_psql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/apache/Dockerfile_postgrtesql
    image: ellakcy/moodle:postgresql_apache
    links:
      - "moodle_psql_db:moodle_db"
      - "moodle_apache_base"
    ports:
      - "6082:80"
    environment:
      MOODLE_DB_HOST: "moodle_psql_db"
      MOODLE_DB_NAME: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MOODLE_DB_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN: "${MOODLE_ADMIN}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_URL: "http://0.0.0.0:6082"

  # Testing mariadb support
  moodle_maria_db:
      image: mariadb
      environment:
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
        MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
        MYSQL_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  moodle_maria:
      image: ellakcy/moodle:mysql_maria_apache
      links:
        - "moodle_mysql"
        - "moodle_maria_db:moodle_db"
      ports:
        - "6081:80"
      environment:
        MOODLE_DB_HOST: "moodle_maria_db"
        MOODLE_DB_NAME: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
        MOODLE_DB_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
        MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
        MOODLE_ADMIN: "${MOODLE_ADMIN}"
        MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
        MOODLE_URL: "http://0.0.0.0:6081"

#Alpine fpm based images



  #Basic alpine fpm image
  alpine_fpm_base:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/fpm_alpine/Dockerfile_base
    image: ellakcy/moodle:alpine_fpm_base

  moodle_mysql_alpine_db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD: "yes"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MYSQL_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}'

  # Mysql Enabled image

  nginx:
   image: nginx:alpine
   ports:
     - "7070:80"
   volumes:
     - './conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'
   links:
     - 'moodle_mysql_alpine'
   volumes_from:
     - 'moodle_mysql_alpine'

  moodle_mysql_alpine:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfiles/fpm_alpine/Dockerfile_mysql
    image: ellakcy/moodle:mysql_maria_fpm_alpine
    links:
      - "moodle_mysql_alpine_db:moodle_db"
      - "alpine_fpm_base"
    environment:
      MOODLE_DB_HOST: "moodle_mysql_alpine_db"
      MOODLE_DB_NAME: "${MOODLE_DB_NAME}"
      MOODLE_DB_USER: '${MOODLE_MYSQL_USER}'
      MOODLE_DB_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN: "${MOODLE_ADMIN}"
      MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD: "${MOODLE_ADMIN_PASSWORD}"
      MOODLE_URL: "http://0.0.0.0:7070/moodle_mysql"
```

And the nginx configuration is:

```
events {
  worker_connections  768;
}

http {
  include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  charset  utf-8;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_disable  "msie6";
  client_max_body_size 10000M;

  server {
    listen  80;

    root  /var/www/www;
    index  index.php;

    location / {
      try_files  $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors  on;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_pass  moodle_mysql_alpine:9000;
    }
  }
}
```

But regardless what I've tried to do is useless I cannot make my `moodle_mysql_alpine` to get served via nginx. Do you fellows have an Idea how I can make it to get served? Also keep in minf that I do not care to keep volumes in my local filesysytem bevcause this file is intended to build and run the images just to upload them to an image repository.

Comment: What is the error in the nginx service output? What URL are you visiting that is giving a 404?

Comment: Show the logs when the 404 occurs. Clear all the logs. Hit the request which you should get answer to and post the logs during that 404 request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did wrong on the root folder. It was `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www/www` one. So the nginx correctly prompted me to the 404 page because there was no file/volume mounted to it.